# Veeva iRep Salesforce - Presentation could not load

Tags: salesforce

I've been having difficulties getting a presentation into my iRep media folder.  I have followed the Veva CLM V21 Content Creations Guide, and I get the following error in "My Alerts" on the iPad app:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH9Kr.jpg

Here is my sales force presentation layout (each slide has a corresponding .zip file with the same name):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pgrr.png

Here is my directory (before I zip them):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/21REV.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you managed to resolve this but here are 2 potential options you can try to resolve:

**Screenshot naming conventions** *(page 32 of Veeva CLM v21 content creation guidelines)*:

- Preview Image - should have **'-full'** on the end i.e. Media1-full.jpg. You appear to be missing the 'full' extension
- Thumbnail image should be 'Media1-thumb.jpg'

**Refresh Database:**

1. Go OPTIONS
2. Database
3. Touch the 'Refresh Database' button > touch YES > and this should refresh everything and then re-sync from scratch. This was the issue with my presentation not displaying...

Let us know if either option works?